# Getting substrings between commas. Why Mid(string,integer,integer) is failing?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, substring

I have a textbox (DropDownList1) that contains a string of 46 characters following this format:

> (string1,string2,string3)

I want to get string values without the commas, this way:

```
a=string1
b=string2
c=string3
```

So I used the below code:

```
Dim a As String
Dim b As String
Dim c As String
Dim x As Integer = InStr(1, DropDownList1.Text, ",", CompareMethod.Text) + 1
Dim y As Integer = InStr(InStr(1, DropDownList1.Text, ",", CompareMethod.Text) + 1, DropDownList1.Text, ",") - 1
Dim z As Integer = Len(DropDownList1.Text)
a = Mid(DropDownList1.Text, 1, InStr(1, DropDownList1.Text, ",", CompareMethod.Text) - 1)
b = Mid(DropDownList1.Text, x, y) _
   'InStr(1, DropDownList1.Text, ",", CompareMethod.Text) + 1, _
   'InStr(InStr(1, DropDownList1.Text, ",", CompareMethod.Text) + 1, DropDownList1.Text, ",") - 1)
c = Mid(DropDownList1.Text, _
    InStr(InStr(1, DropDownList1.Text, ",", CompareMethod.Text) + 1, DropDownList1.Text, ",") + 1, _
    Len(DropDownList1.Text))
```

However, when I debug it happens:

x=18 (which is correct with the string I was using)
y=42 (correct too)
z=46 (correct)
a=string1 (yes!)
c=string3 (yes again!)

and b=string2,string3 ----->what happened here?

Can you please tell what is wrong with my code? I simply don't get it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming x,y, and z are just for debugging, and it's really a,b, and c that you care about, and that there are no commas or parenthese in the important parts of your string:

```
Dim values = DropDownList1.Text.Replace("(","").Replace(")","").Split(","c)
Dim a as String = values(0)
Dim b As String = values(1)
Dim c As String = values(2)
```

Comment: Yes, it works and solves my main problem. Thought I was expecting someone debugs my code and explains me what was wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Use the Split() function on the string, applying it to some string array variable, and then assigning the values to your variables as needed if you still want to.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that function. However I still don't understand why my previous logic didn't work.

Comment: The third parameter of Mid is the _length_, not the end position of the string. In your example it takes the next 42 characters starting from the 18th character.

Answer (score 1):

If in fact you're using VB.NET you can use the [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) function.

```
Dim text As String = "a,b,c"
Dim parts As String() = text.Split(CChar(","))
Dim a As String = parts(0)
Dim b As String = parts(1)
Dim c As String = parts(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try...

```
Private Sub ParseMyString()
    Dim TargetString() As String = Split("string1,string2,string3", ",")
    Dim Count As Integer = 0
    Dim Result As String
    Const ASC_OFFSET As Integer = 97

    Result = ""
    Do Until Count > UBound(TargetString)
        Result = Result & Chr(ASC_OFFSET + Count) & "=" & TargetString(Count) & vbCrLf
        Count = Count + 1
    Loop
    MsgBox(Result)
End Sub
```